# Bing Maps v7. Direction manager: callback with parameters

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

For example, I have three addresses in my 'myAddress' collection:

№, IdAddress,  Address

1, 255,  New York street1

2, 256,  New York street2

3, 257,  New York street3

Then I put them in directionsManager and call calculateDirections():

```
var waypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({address: myAddress[i].address });
mapObj.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint);
mapObj.directionsManager.calculateDirections();
```

Question: how to put IdAddress in waypoint? I need to process response by IdAddress, not by Address description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
waypoint.YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME = YOUR_VARIABLE;
```